# Importing only the heading row which is in 2nd row using laravel matwebsite

Tags: excel, laravel, upload, maatwebsite-excel

How to Importing only the heading row which is in 2nd row using laravel maatwebsite?

This is my controller code:

```
  HeadingRowFormatter::default('none');

   $headings = (new HeadingRowImport)->toArray($request['student_upload_file']);
```

This will get the first row. I need the second row.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the second row by passing 2 as the HeadingRowImport argument.

```php
$headings = (new HeadingRowImport(2))->toArray($request['student_upload_file']);
```

https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/blob/3.1/src/HeadingRowImport.php#L23-L34